# Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'> when trying to loop through files

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I have the below code updated; in effort to allow my script to loop through multiple files in a directory (as opposed to one):

```
@classmethod
def find_file(cls):
     all_files = list()
     """"Finds the excel file to process"""
     archive = ZipFile(config.FILE_LOCATION)
     for file in archive.filelist:
        if file.filename.__contains__('Horrible Data Site '):
             all_files.append(archive.extract(file.filename, config.UNZIP_LOCATION))
     return all_files
```

Before declaring '`all files = list()`' above in my `find_files` method, this was working **on one file** in the directory. I added the `all_files` in attempt to allow loop through all files in a directory.

Also, in the below `main.py` I just added the `for` right before `PENDING_RECORDS` for this objective.

```
"""Start Point"""

from data.find_pending_records import FindPendingRecords
from vital.vital_entry import VitalEntry
from time import sleep

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try: 
        for PENDING_RECORDS in FindPendingRecords().get_excel_data():
            # Do operations on PENDING_RECORDS

            # Reads excel to map data from excel to vital
            MAP_DATA = FindPendingRecords().get_mapping_data()

            # Configures Driver
            VITAL_ENTRY = VitalEntry()

            # Start chrome and navigate to vital website
            VITAL_ENTRY.instantiate_chrome()

            # Begin processing Records
            VITAL_ENTRY.process_records(PENDING_RECORDS, MAP_DATA)

            print (PENDING_RECORDS)
            print("All done")     
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
```

The addition of adding the `all_files()` and `for` now outputs the following error in the Anaconda Prompt:

```
(base) C:\Python>python main.py
Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

**this is the config.py**

```
FILE_LOCATION = r"C:\Zip\DATA Docs.zip"
UNZIP_LOCATION = r"C:\Zip\Pending"
VITAL_URL = 'http://horriblewebsite:8080/START'
HEADLESS = False
PROCESSORS = 4
MAPPING_DOC = ".//map/mappingDOC.xlsx"
```

Comment: Why is `find_file` a class method? You never use `cls` in its definition. It's also not clear where `find_file` gets used. You're also doing to much in the `try` block; we have no idea what is actually raising whatever exception you catch. Get rid of the `try`/`except`, and show us the traceback produced by the uncaught exception.

Comment: What is `config.FILE_LOCATION` in that function? Is it a `str` or `list`?

Comment: Also, per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) `ZipFile` supports the `with` context manager, and as such should be used when opening the file

Comment: @PeterGibbons Can you replace `print(exc)` with `raise` and show the full stack trace? `print(exc)` truncates output